# how R recursive feature elimination with logistic regression

Tags: r, r-caret, feature-selection

In fact, there is a similar question and answer, but it does not work me. see below. The trick lies in rewrite fit of `lmFunc`.

> "Error in { : task 1 failed - "Results do not have equal lengths", many warning:glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred"

where is the fault?

```
lmFuncs$fit=function (x, y, first, last, ...) 
{
  tmp <- as.data.frame(x) 
  tmp$y <- y
  glm(y ~ ., data = tmp, family=binomial(link='logit'))
}
ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = lmFuncs,method = 'cv',number=10)
fit.rfe=rfe(df.preds,df.depend, rfeControl=ctrl)
```

And in the rfeControl help, it is said the parameter 'functions' that can be **used with caret’s train function (caretFuncs)**. What does it really mean?
Any details and example? Thanks

Comment: Read [how to ask reproducible  question in r?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue with customising lmFunc.

For logistic regression make sure you use **lr**Funcs and set size equal to the number of predictor variables. This leads to no issues.

**Example *(for functionality purposes only)***

```
library(caret)
#Reproducible data
set.seed(1) 
x <- data.frame(runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10))
x$dpen <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10)
x$dpen <- factor(x$dpen)

#Spliting training set into two parts based on outcome: 80% and 20%
index <- createDataPartition(x$dpen, p=0.8, list=FALSE)
trainSet <- x[ index,]
testSet <- x[-index,]

control <- rfeControl(functions = lrFuncs,
                   method = "cv", #cross validation
                   verbose = FALSE, #prevents copious amounts of output from being produced.
                   )

##RFE
rfe(trainSet[,1:28] #predictor varia, 
    trainSet[,9], 
    sizes = c(1:28) #size of predictor variables, 
    rfeControl = control)
```